# What's wrong here when I compute $\operatorname{Gal} (x^4 -2 / \mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Maybe that's a stupid question and I'm missing something very trivial. Let $f(x) = x^4 - 2$ and $\alpha_1 = \sqrt[4]2, \alpha_2 = -\sqrt[4]2, \alpha_3 = i\sqrt[4]2, \alpha_4 = -i\sqrt[4]2$ be its roots, then $\mathbb{Q}_f = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2, i\sqrt[4]2) = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[4]2, i) $ since $\zeta_4 = i, -i$ .

Now let $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_f/\mathbb{Q})$, then $|G| = (\mathbb{Q}_f:\mathbb{Q}) = 8$ and $G \leq S_4$ is a transitive group. Therefore $G = D_4$. Now consider the inclusion $ i:\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, it can be extended in four different ways to $\varphi_i: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2) \hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ where $\varphi_i (\alpha_1) = \alpha_i$ and $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$. For each $i$, there are two extensions $\psi_{ij} :\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2, i\sqrt[4]2) \hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}} $ where $\psi_{ij} (\alpha_3) = \alpha_j$ and $j = 3, 4$. However $\psi_{44}$ is not a permutation of the roots. What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TTS I've edited properly

Answer (score 1):

I think your $\psi_{uv}$ are not right. You should choose $\psi_{uv}(\alpha_{3}) = \alpha_{v}$, where $v \in \{ 3, 4 \}$ if $u \in \{ 1, 2 \}$, or $v \in \{ 1, 2 \}$ if $u \in \{ 3, 4 \}$.

(I have avoided the index $i$ because of a conflict with the complex number $i$.)

Another way of seeing this is that you can extend $\varphi_{u}$ in two ways, by choosing $i \mapsto i$ or $i \mapsto -i$.

Comment: Why? For the second extension the minimal polynomial is $(x-\alpha_3)(x -\alpha_4)$, then you can extend any morphism $\varphi : K \hookrightarrow \overline{K}$ to a morphism $\psi_u$, such that $\psi_u : K(\alpha_3) \hookrightarrow \overline{K}$ and $\psi_u (\alpha_3) = \alpha_u$ and $u = 3, 4$

Comment: @user40276, if you have already mapped $\alpha_{1}$ to $\alpha_{3}$, say (and thus $- \alpha_{1}$ to $- \alpha_{3} = \alpha_{4}$), to preserve injectivity you cannot map $\alpha_{3}$ onto $\pm \alpha_{3}$. (More in the next comment on your extension.)

Comment: @user40276, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_{3}$ over $K = \Bbb{Q}(\alpha_{1})$ is indeed $g = (x - \alpha_{3})(x - \alpha_{4}) = x^{2} + (\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2}) x + \dfrac{2}{\alpha_{1} \alpha_{2}}$, but now this allows you to map $\alpha_{3}$ onto a root of *the image of the polynomial $g$ under $\varphi_{u}$*. And this image visibly depends on what you have mapped $\alpha_{1}$ onto.

Comment: Why? $K(u) = K(v)$ if $u$ and $v$ have the same minimal polynomial over $K$.

Comment: @user40276, please review the proof (that you must have in your books) of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem

Comment: @user40276, also note that $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $i \sqrt[4]{2}$ have the same minimal polynomial $x^4 - 2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, but clearly $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \ne \Bbb{Q}(i \sqrt[4]{2})$.

Comment: That´s not the problem. If both have the same minimal polynomial, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4 - 2) = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]2)$. Apparently the problem is that, when $\varphi (\sqrt[4]2) =  i\sqrt[4]2$, the minimal polynomial in the image becomes $(x - \sqrt[4]2)(x + \sqrt[4]2)$, then the extensions of $\varphi$ must be a permutation of these roots in the image of $\varphi$.

Comment: @user40276, you are writing equalities where you should have written isomorphisms.